Script doesn't run through my methods every time
So, I am building a level procedural generator. I'm sort of following blackthornprod's tutorial while implementing a grid rather than moving the level generator.
EDIT: Ok, I've changed the code completely, but now it ping-pongs on the row just before the last row of the grid. It still doesn't go through to the bottom to activate the stopGeneration bool.
I've replaced the old code with the new below. But it is still causing me issues. Any suggestions?


using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;


//Code by Kristine Westman
/*TODO - figure out why the rooms sometimes to run through the entire program before stopping.
         Examples: 1 or 2 rooms will spawn before it stops. Or the program will stop before hitting (x,0) for a position. 


 */

enum Direction
{
    MoveLeft, 
    MoveRight, 
    MoveDown
}

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LevelGenerator Instance; 

    [SerializeField] private Tilemap gameMap; // to set the room tiles down. This works with my spawner object. 

    public int width, height; // size of the level. This can be modified and changed based on level or plan for player to choose size of grid. 
    public int cellSize; //Size of the rooms (20 is what is planned)

    int xAxis, yAxis; // used to move along the grid.
    Direction direction; // direction to move along the grid - Left, right, or down
    int randDirection; 

    bool stopGeneration = false; // keeps the Generator running

    [SerializeField] GameObject[] roomTypes; // 0 - LeftRight, 1 - LeftRightBot, 2 - LeftRightTop, 3 - AllSides
    GameObject currentRoom;

    //bool outOfBounds = false;
    private int lastX; // saves last x before new x is made
    private int lastY; // saves last y before new y is made

    int leftCount = 0;
    int rightCount = 0;
    int downCount = 0; 

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
        }

    }

    void Start()
    {

        //Starting Room 

        stopGeneration = false;
        int randStartingPos = Random.Range(0, width);

        xAxis = randStartingPos; 
        yAxis = height - 1; // to keep the first room inside bounds

        int randRoom = Random.Range(0, 4); 
        SetRoom(xAxis, yAxis, roomTypes[randRoom]);

        GetDirection(1, 6); 

        Move(); //test - still hangs even here
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        if (stopGeneration == false)  //should run until last room tries to go below the y-bounds
        {
            Move();
            print("StopGen = " + stopGeneration); //See where StopGen is for error testing. 
        }

    }

    private void Move()
    {
        print("Starting Move()"); 

        if (direction == Direction.MoveRight) // Move Right
        {
            rightCount++;
            leftCount = 0;
            downCount = 0; 

            if (rightCount == 2) { direction = Direction.MoveDown; return; }

            print("moving right"); 
            xAxis += 1;

            int randRoom = Random.Range(0, 4);
            SetRoom(xAxis, yAxis, roomTypes[randRoom]);

            GetDirection(1,6);
            print("Direction: " + direction);

            print("ending Move()");

        }

        else if (direction == Direction.MoveLeft) // Move Left
        {
            rightCount = 0;
            leftCount++;
            downCount = 0;

            if (leftCount == 2) { direction = Direction.MoveDown; return; }

            print("moving left");
            xAxis -= 1;
            int randRoom = Random.Range(0, 4);
            SetRoom(xAxis, yAxis, roomTypes[randRoom]);

            GetDirection(3, 6); 
            print("Direction: " + direction);

            print("ending Move()");


        }

        else if (direction == Direction.MoveDown) // Move Down
        {
            rightCount = 0;
            leftCount = 0;
            downCount++;

            print("moving down");

                if (currentRoom.GetComponent<RoomType>().type != RoomTypes.LeftRightBot || currentRoom.GetComponent<RoomType>().type != RoomTypes.All) //checks that the room that was placed has an opening down
                {
                    currentRoom.GetComponent<RoomType>().RoomDestruction(); // destroys the tiles on the tile map
                    SetRoom(xAxis, yAxis, roomTypes[3]); // replaces old room
                }


                yAxis -= 1;
                int randRoom = Random.Range(2, 4);
                SetRoom(xAxis, yAxis, roomTypes[randRoom]); 

                GetDirection(1, 6);
                print("Direction: " + direction);
        }

        print("End Move()"); 

    }

    private void GetDirection( int firstLimit, int limit) 
    {
        randDirection = Random.Range(firstLimit, limit);

        Direction lastDirection = direction; 

        //set's  the direction
        if (randDirection == 1 || randDirection == 2) { direction = Direction.MoveRight; }
            
        else if (randDirection == 3 || randDirection == 4) { direction = Direction.MoveLeft; }
            
        else if (randDirection == 5) { direction = Direction.MoveDown; }


        //checks that direction won't turn left after turning right
        if (lastDirection == Direction.MoveRight && randDirection == 3) { direction = Direction.MoveRight; }

        else if (lastDirection == Direction.MoveRight && randDirection == 4) { direction = Direction.MoveDown; }


        //Checks boundries
        if ((xAxis < 0 && direction == Direction.MoveLeft) || (xAxis > width && direction == Direction.MoveRight))
        {
            direction = Direction.MoveDown;
        }

        if (yAxis < 0 && direction == Direction.MoveDown)
        {
            stopGeneration = true;
        }
        


    }

    public void SetRoom(int x, int y, GameObject room)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && y > 0 && x < width && y < height)
        {
            lastX = x; lastY = y;
            print("Setting up Room");
            currentRoom = Instantiate(room, GetWorldPosition(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
            print("Room Position: " + currentRoom.transform.position + ", " + currentRoom.transform.position); //For debug purposes
        }

        else
        {
            print("Room out of bounds"); // error check and debug purposes
            xAxis = lastX; yAxis = lastY;

            if (yAxis < 0) { stopGeneration = true; }
            else if (xAxis < 0 || xAxis > width) { direction = Direction.MoveDown; }; 
           
            return; 
        }
    }

    public void SetTile(Vector3Int position, TileBase tile) //How the game sets the tiles to use Rule Tiles
    {

        gameMap.SetTile(position, null);
        gameMap.SetTile(position, tile); 
    }

    public void RemoveTile(Vector3Int position) //Clears the room. Used by the Room's script. But access here. Had trouble when used on the Room prefrab. 
    {
        gameMap.SetTile(position, null);
    }

    public Vector3 GetWorldPosition(int x, int y) // Basic math to figure out the position on the grid based on the origin position and the cell size. 
    {
        int xPos = (x * cellSize) + (int)transform.position.x;
        int yPos = (y * cellSize) + (int)transform.position.y; 

        return new Vector3(xPos, yPos);
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameLevel"); //Resets the scene -- I have a debug button that uses this to test. 
    }


The only thing I might change is do a debug check on the direction to see if I am getting some unexpected number.
If anyone has ideas, I'd appreciate it.
I've rewritten a lot of the code. Added the enums to check for direction rather than using ints. I created a new method to get the direction. And I tried to reset position when the room goes out of bounds. It still does not activate the stop bool to complete the code, and starts to ping-pong on the x,1 position.

then you need more debug messages, to show you whats going on and why it stops or what its doing
